# Change content of text with Ajax in pug

Tags: javascript, ajax, button, pug

I have to use Ajax on my website for a school project. I want to change the content of a button, but I first wanted to be able to change some text. I've found some examples on how to change text in a pug-file but they never seem to be working. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Pug:

```
extends layout

block content
    #reizen.w3-content.w3-container.w3-padding-64
        //test ajax        
        #demo
            h2 The XMLHttpRequest Object
            button(type='button' onclick='loadDoc()') Change Content

    block content
    script.
        function loadDoc() {
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
                    this.responseText;
                }
            };

            xhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
            xhttp.send();
        }
```

And I have also a little file, ajax_info.txt, in the root map (the pug file is in the views-map) with only:

```
Ajax is cool!
```

The result is always some text: The XMLHttpRequest Object, 
and under the text a button with, Change content, but nothing happens when I click on it.

Comment: You should read [this article](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) on how to approach using StackOverflow for homework assignments.

Answer (score 0):

Pug is a completely separate paradigm from Ajax.  Ajax is used to make a request from a server without reloading a page, and pug dynamically renders pages when they are requested from the server.  A pug application involves building multiple pages, and an Ajax application uses one page.

You can generate the HTML and JavaScript using pug, but that's where the pug ends.  It simply can't be used in Ajax calls.

You should look into Ajax libraries like Axios or jQuery and focus your attention there.  You can use Express (without pug) to handle your API calls.